# How to have one of my methods called when a preference value is changed by a slider

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, cocoa-bindings

I have an nsslider in my window and I binded its value to nsuserdefaults. Is it possible, using cocoa bindings to invoke a method whenever its value is changed? I can get its value from userdefaults, but I don't know its its changed or not at any given time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Observe the `NSUserDefaults` instance for key/value changes and react to `observeValueForKey` messages.

Comment: NSUserDefaults isn't observable.

Answer (score 0):

[Add yourself as an observer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/addObserver%3aforKeyPath%3aoptions%3acontext%3a) for [the user defaults controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/index.html#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSUserDefaultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004148)'s `@"value.preferenceKeyHere"`. Then, you'll need to respond to [the observation message](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/observeValueForKeyPath%3aofObject%3achange%3acontext%3a), check the observed object and key path (or set a context pointer when you begin observing and check *that* in your response to the observation message), and update your knowledge of the preference's value accordingly.

See also [the Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/).